# Unchecking checkbox during live search with Blaze in Meteor JS

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am trying to simulate a live search with Meteor JS (btw, surprisingly tough task!)

This is in `client.js`:

```
Template.newDiagnostic.events({
    "keyup .entry-search": function(e) {
        Session.set("search-query", e.currentTarget.value)
    }
})
Template.registerHelper("searchQuery", function(value){
    var query = new RegExp(Session.get("search-query"))
    return query.test(value)
})
Template.newDiagnostic.helpers({
    symptoms: function() {
        return Symptoms.find({})
    }
})
```

Basically, I have an event, watching the keyup in the search input, changing a session variable.
Next, I registered a helper to check if a given string match (RegExp) that session variable.
Lastly, the helper is only to provide the data.

Then, I have this in my HTML:

```
<template name="newDiagnostic">
<input type="text" class="form-control entry-search" placeholder="Filtrar por nome">
    {{#each symptoms}}
        {{#if searchQuery name}}
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input class="checkbox-symptoms" type="checkbox" value="{{_id}}"> {{name}}
                </label>
             </div>
        {{/if}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

Here, I try to filter (hiding) entries not in the query.

The simulates live search works fine so far: you type something in that input text and the entries are filtered.
The problem is when you search for something and check an entry.
Then, if you search for another term and check for that one, your first checked entry is gone.
I don't want this behaviour.
I want to search for an entry, check it, search for another entry, check it too, and so on.

I think that this problem has to do with the reloading of the template, but I have no idea how to get this working.
I thought about saving the checked entries in a Session variable, but that would be my last option.
I have also tried `matteodem:easy-search`, but the same problem happens.

Comment: why don't you get the current 'checked' values, stored on an array per user, and showing on a different '{{#each}}?, and show them down list of checkbox like "Checked by you" or something

Comment: Hi, @Ethaan. Thanks for replying. I would like to avoid saving the checked entries for consulting later... I was looking first for a solution more "locally", that is, something using only blaze or Templates itself. But, of course, if that's not possible, I'll hardcode a solution saving checked entries in a Session variable or something like that. Thanks, anyway.